# Create array from mysql query. Column2 as key Column 1 as value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains

```
column 1 = state  column 2 = link
Alabama             auburn.alabama.com
Alabama             bham.alabama.com
Alabama             dothan.alabama.com
```

I need to grab from my database table and put into an array that i can array_walk() through. they need to be accessed like this array.

```
$arraytable = array(
"auburn.alabama.com"=>"Alabama",
"bham.alabama.com"=>"Alabama",
"dothan.alabama.com"=>"Alabama",
);
```

I have tried everything but not sure how make this work using php to print the array like such. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note** Your question title is inconsistent with your example.  In the title you ask for column 1 as the key, but your example uses column 2 as the key.  I've used column 2 here...

It isn't clear what MySQL API you are using to fetch, but whichever it is, use the associative fetch method and create new array keys using the pattern `$arraytable[$newkey] = $newvalue`. This example would be in object-oriented MySQLi:

```
$arraytable = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  // Create a new array key with the 'link' and assign the 'state'
  $arraytable[$row['link']] = $row['state'];
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! works great. was just getting ready to post my solution and seen this answer is much more simple. This is the greatest resource around. Thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_column for this, since PHP5.5 (http://php.net/array_column)

> Description
>
> array array_column ( array $array , mixed $column_key [, mixed $index_key = null ] )
>
> array_column() returns the values from a single column of the array, identified by the column_key. Optionally, you may provide an index_key to index the values in the returned array by the values from the index_key column in the input array.

For PHP < 5.5:
https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php

Comment: note: I realize this is an old question, but someone pasted the link into IRC as a cross-reference to their question. So I figured it would be useful to reference the new function here, for future users.

Answer (score 1):

To implement AcidReign's suggestion, here is the snippet:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BBFGt))

```
$resultset = [
    ['state' => 'Alabama', 'link' => 'auburn.alabama.com'],
    ['state' => 'Alabama', 'link' => 'bham.alabama.com'],
    ['state' => 'Alabama', 'link' => 'dothan.alabama.com']
];

var_export(array_column($resultset, 'state', 'link'));
//                                            ^^^^-- use this column's data for keys
//                                   ^^^^^-- use this column's data for values
```

Output:

```
array (
  'auburn.alabama.com' => 'Alabama',
  'bham.alabama.com' => 'Alabama',
  'dothan.alabama.com' => 'Alabama',
)
```

---

However, `array_column()` won't directly work on a result set object, but a `foreach()` can immediately access the data set using array syntax without any fetching function calls.

Body-less foreach: ([Demo](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/70538fff3ca4f9a22dd40e87c8f89c26/php/php8/075aed7fe9143171988315387dae66a9/))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM my_table') as ['link' => $link, 'state' => $result[$link]]);
var_export($result);
```

Or a foreach with a body: ([Demo](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/70538fff3ca4f9a22dd40e87c8f89c26/php/php8/f8dca6a8b01aa256c77d96da00c3013c/))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM my_table') as $row) {
    $result[$row['link']] = $row['state'];
}
var_export($result);
```

All of the above snippets return:

```
array (
  'auburn.alabama.com' => 'Alabama',
  'bham.alabama.com' => 'Alabama',
  'dothan.alabama.com' => 'Alabama',
)
```